# Asp.net Web api The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to build a Web API which accepts a string parameter and return a string value,but I always get the error, The requested resource does not support HTTP method `GET`. I searched a bit in the stack overflow and added the line `[AcceptVerbs("GET")]` but I still got the error. Could any one help me out?

Global.asax.cs file

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "sasRoute",
                routeTemplate: "api/sas/{container}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "sas",
                    container = RouteParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

Controller's method

```
[Route("{container}")]
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[HttpGet]
public string GetContainerToken(string container)
{
    return container;
}
```

Comment: What URL are you attempting?

Comment: @PaulAbbott http://localhost:52896/api/sas/test

Comment: You should try:
            [Route("/api/mobile/{container}")]
            [HttpGet]
            public string GetContainerToken(string container)
            {
                return container;
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to register **Custom Route**, as you already have **Attribute Route**.

Remove it from your code. Instead, you will need **RoutePrefix**.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/sas")]
public class SasController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{container}")]
    public string Get(string container)
    {
        return container;
    }
}
```